# Highcharts event on animation complete?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dom-events

Is there any way to set an event listener on when animation is **finished** on Highcharts redraw? From what I see, a `redraw` event fires immediately on change, without waiting for animation. Or maybe there's some other way to wait for when the chart has become still?

Besides, is it possible to add an event listener to the chart that's already rendered (e.g. via `addEventListener`, not by JSON configuration)?

Comment: But in general what is your goal, for which purpose you need to have "funished animation" event?

Comment: On high level, I am writing Selenium automation for a product where Highcharts are used, and I cannot think of many ways to wait until the chart has rendered and become still. Because of variety of charts that's not very feasible to poll for some DOM change, however if there's no way to hook up an event listener, I'll have to go that way.

Answer (score 11):

You can catch animation event and set complete function.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: {
                complete: function () {
                    console.log('a1');
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G63h4/

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to add this event listener dynamically after chart is already rendered? something like

$('#container').on("plotOptions.series.animation.complete", function(){...});

Comment: You can try to use series.update({animation:{//code}}) http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update

Comment: You should be able to catch the animation event as per Sebastians answer, but this is not reliable and should not be used. The posted fiddle itself only works half the time in Chrome44 and IE11, the other half of the time it fires the event twice event though we just have one series. There is currently no good way to do this. Awaiting Highcharts to fix bug.

Comment: Have you an example of unworking my solution? Then I will verify that and request as possibly bug, if exists.

Comment: It works but It is not called always. Sometimes log prints sometimes log does not print. for reference http://jsfiddle.net/Lra2d9ku/54/

Answer (score 2):

There is another event after animation is finished which is fired just once:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      animation: {
        complete: function () {
          console.log('a1 - fired after animation of each element');
        },
        events: {
          afterAnimate: function (ev) {
            console.log('fired only once for each series');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: the property "events" should be inside "series", not inside "animation"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "complete" callback on the animation argument of chart.redraw.

E.g.:

```
chart.redraw({
    complete: function(){
      console.log("Animation completed");
    }
});
```